# Write page title in URL instead of page ID

Tags: javascript, php, web, e-commerce

I am having my website and whenever I add a new page into it, it creates an url with random id number which I don't want. I would like to use the `page/product` name as my URL, so what currently I am having is:

Current: `http://www.abcdex.in/deal/d29e96cfd623a83f37f1bc12b4465131`

Desired: `http://www.abcdex.in/deal/Product-Name`

I have gone through with my `.htaccess` file and it shows at the bottom the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|forum|robots\.txt|canvas\.xml)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Could anyone help me out because It is creating a lot of mess and I am loosing my site rank because of this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is called `Human Readable URL` and it is better to solve this issue at your contant management system level - the system that manage your site. Check there option `Human Readable URL`

Comment: does the url change when a form is submitted? that is maybe when you click on a product?

Comment: @kapil sharma I have pasted an exampler learn from that and apply there if any doubts feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

learn from this example and apply in your .htaccess
Example

```
  AddDefaultCharset utf-8
 Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteBase /living/
 # skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
 #RewriteRule ^ - [L]
 #RewriteRule ^authors/([^/]*)\.html$ main.php?authchar=$1 [QSA,L]
```

your .htaccess will be something like this your filenames

```
  AddDefaultCharset utf-8
  Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
  RewriteEngine on 
  RewriteBase /
 # skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
 #RewriteRule ^ - [L]
 #RewriteRule ^deal/([^/]*)\.html$ yourscript.php?d29e96cfd623a83f37f1bc12b4465131=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try do all of this in htaccess, but I like to solve these issues in PHP

On all of your pages with URLs similar to

```
http://www.abcdex.in/deal/d29e96cfd623a83f37f1bc12b4465131
```

Convert the product name into a variable, such as $ProductName

Then redirect:

```
 <?php 
 header("Location: http://www.abcdex.in/deal/'.$ProductName.'"); 
 ?>
```

It is better if you alter the header into a 301 moved permanently, but you will only be able to alter the header if the Product-Name is passed into the variable $ProductName before any parts of the page have been loaded.

```
 header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
```

If you can't alter the header, then there are ways to redirect in PHP without using the header. I believe the following code works:

```
 $URL="http://www.abcdex.in/deal/'.$ProductName.'";
 echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;URL=' . $URL . '">';
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='{$URL}';       </script>";
```